# WinSCP sending a file via console?

Tags: winscp

I am using WinSCP scripting for my backups and i wanted to know how to push one file to the remote server?

I would then like to [execute the script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call), which I know how to do. It's just sending the one file, without using sync that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the very same page you linked to there is a `put` command (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put). Didn't you even look?

Comment: I did but uhh. I feel stupid. I notice call and sync but not that even while looking for an upload option.